# Jenkins is unable to execute Cucumber tests using Maven Surefire, Spring Boot and JUnit5

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, junit5, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.2.6.RELEASE` and `cucumber-java8:5.6.0` to execute e2e tests using Cucumber Runner/Spring Boot/JUnit5/Maven Surefire. I have installed latest Jenkins Community LTS v2.222.1 on a Linux VM and connected my laptop as a slave.

When I execute the tests on my laptop using IDE / command prompt it works fine (using `mvn clean test`). However same tests are not running when triggered from Jenkins. It's bit confusing since I am using same config/tools.

**Jenkins Console O/P:**

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to C:\Jenkins\workspace\Sanity\core\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ project-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
Apr 07, 2020 1:08:45 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser parseForFeature
INFO: File {0} does not contain features
Apr 07, 2020 1:08:45 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser parseJsonFiles
INFO: File 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\2\cucumber5203280546924184867.json' contains 0 features
Apr 07, 2020 1:08:45 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder generateErrorPage
INFO: Unexpected error
net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: Passed files have no features!
...
```

**IDE Console O/P:**

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to C:\Code\project\core\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ project-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.x.y.z.CucumberTests
2020-04-07 13:22:52.330  INFO   --- [           main] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.x.y.z.stepdefs.LogVerificationSteps], using SpringBootContextLoader
...
```

**CucumberTests.java:**

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "de.monochromata.cucumber.report.PrettyReports:target"},
        features = "src/test/resources/features")
public class CucumberTests {

}
```

This is multi-module maven project, the features are available under:

```
 root
 \__core
  \__src/test/resources/features/*
```

So basically in Jenkins features/tests are not being run at all - why is it happening, any idea folks?

Comment: Can u try with giving the full path to the generated cucumber json file "de.monochromata.cucumber.report.PrettyReports:target/...../cucumber-json.json"

Comment: @Grasshopper the cucumber json file will be generated once the test execution happens, in my case there is no test running at all. Also I am not using json reporter so the json report being referred here is a different one, you can see the path in the jenkins console o/p shown above. The de.monochromata plugin generates the html report in target.

Comment: oops my bad... read the original post again and u mentioned that tests are not running. Check this out - https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/issues/628. Possibly an encoding thing.

Comment: No prob, thanks for the pointer. However it does not look like the root cause.